# Syntax for setting multi-value lookup fields in SPD 2013 workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I'm trying to set the value of a field in a lookup column using a SPD 2013 workflow. The column is set to allow multiple values in the lookup.

I've seen many sources stating that the syntax for achieving this is either `id1;#;#id2;#;#id3` or `id1;#value1;#id2;#value2;#id3;#value3`, where `id` and `value` are the ID of the list item and the value from the lookup field respectively. However, people are usually referring to SPD 2010 workflows, and [this post](http://www.concurrency.com/blog/setting-multi-value-lookup-column-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow-part-2/) suggests that this syntax cannot be used in 2013 workflows.

I want to use a native SPD 2013 workflow but when I tried the methods above they both fail with the following error:

"*An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.*"

From this I assumed that I should be providing some kind of JSON object of the form `{"results":[id1,id2,id3]}` or `{"results":[{"Id":id1,"Value":value1"},{"Id":id2,"Value":value2},{"Id":id3,"Value":value3}]}`, which is what you get if you retrieve an existing field as a string. I attempted to build a dictionary with some test values, but I still got the same error.

Am I heading in the right direction here? Is this even possible with SPD 2013 workflows? I'd appreciate any advice on this subject.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking to accomplish the same thing recently.  I tried similar methods as you with the old/new 2010/2013 multi-value lookup syntax as well as trying to pass through a JSON object/dictionary item.  I posted a thread over at MS (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b838bd28-3dea-4137-a3ea-f8939f6281b4/updating-multivalue-lookup-fields-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows), and while I didn't get any assistance, I did eventually find a solution.

Essentially, "Method 1" from my post should be the solution you're looking for.  To recap that here (I'm not up-to-date on posting rules here): Multi-value lookup fields can't be updated in a 2013 workflow and so you need to call a 2010 workflow and pass it the parameters needed to update the multi-value lookup field.

Now in my case, I had an extra snag where this method was failing for me on certain document library items using the new 2013 syntax of ID1;#;#ID2;#;#ID3.  This works for list items just fine, as well as certain file types, but seems to fail on various Office file types (Word/Excel for sure, didn't test others).  The solution there was to just use the old 2010 syntax - ID1;#Value1;#ID2;#Value2;#ID3;#Value3.

Unfortunately, it feels like a huge step back from 2010.  I don't think 2010 workflows (in Designer 2013) can even successfully pull multi-value lookup fields, so even in the simplest case, you have to use a 2013 workflow to fetch the field values and then parse them out to build the correct syntax before passing them through to a 2010 workflow to update.

It's such a huge step backwards, I'm sitting here wondering if I just dove too far off the deep end to see that I'm massively over-complicating things now.  Regardless, hope that helps.

Jordan

Comment: Thank you! The "new 2013 syntax" helped me to create a replacement "Predecessors" field in NewForm and EditForm on a very large list.