# How to set MultiLookupField in Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, lookup-column, multiple-values

I'm working on SharePoint 2016 OnPremise, Workflow 2013 and I'm trying to set a `MultiLookupField` with one ore more values. I tryied to set `1;#2;#3;#4` and `1;#;#2;#;#3;#;#4`, or for one single item `1;#;#` and `1;#`. Then I tryied to add the correct lookupValue `1;#Test1` and `1;#Test1;#2;#Test2;#3;#Test3` but nothing worked. The Worklows tells the following error:

```
An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.
```

I already read post like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1558f8a9-ecd2-47cb-b228-79a7beabdeb6/sharepoint-2013-lookup-column-add-multiple-values-with-workflow?forum=sharepointdevelopment) and [this](https://concurrency.com/blog/w/setting-a-multi-value-lookup-column-using-sharepoi), they did not help.

A possible solution would be to create a WF2010 and start it from the current WF, but I'd avoid the need of a second WF...

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I suggest you create a SharePoint 2010 workflow to update the multiple lookup column, then in your SharePoint 2013 workflow, use "Start a list workflow" to call the SharePoint 2010 workflow.

More information about starting a SharePoint 2010 workflow in SharePoint 2013 workflow:
[How to Start a SharePoint 2010 Workflow Within a SharePoint 2013 Workflow Using SharePoint Designer 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-start-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-within-a-sharepoint/)

A similar thread for your reference:
[Syntax for setting multi-value lookup fields in SPD 2013 workflows](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147292/syntax-for-setting-multi-value-lookup-fields-in-spd-2013-workflows)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I already wrote in the question, I'd like to avoid the creation of a 2010 workflow.

Comment: if you don't want to create a SharePoint 2010 workflow, you can try to use "Call HTTP web service" action to update the column. A similar thread for your referenece: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/897ea128-d888-4567-9e0e-cbd58c2289d3/updating-loopup-field-using-sp-designer-2013-workflow-and-call-http-web-service?forum=sharepointdevelopment